# jQuery: How can I detect offset that page will return on refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, refresh, offset, onready

If you use $("body").offset() onready the result is always 0, even if the url includes an anchor.

Is there a better way to get the offset of where the page will actually resolve to?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats because `$("body").offset()` returns the top and left values of the body relative to the page.

You probably want to use

```
$(window).scrollTop();
```

if you want the value of the scroll position.

```
//this will alert the scroll pos on load
$(document).ready(function(){

    var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();
    alert(scrollPos);

});
```

Comment: Thx! Adding a delay is a bit of a hack, but it's probably the right short-term solution. There's got to be a better way, though, to detect where the screen is going to jump to...

Comment: my bad! used body instead of window. i have updated my answer accordingly. also no timeout is needed.

Answer (score 0):

> - **DEMO 3:** http://jsbin.com/aroha5/3

```
$.fn.extend({
  scrollTo : function(speed, easing) {
    return this.each(function() {
      var targetOffset = $(this).offset().top;
      $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, speed, easing);
    });
  }
});
$('#scroll-to').scrollTo(1000);
```

---

> - **DEMO:** http://jsbin.com/aroha5
> - **DEMO2:** http://jsbin.com/aroha5/2

```
/* body offset start */ $('body').offset().top 
/* body offset end */  $('body').height()
```

*however `$("body").offset()` return an `Object` not `0`*

Comment: $('body').offset().top will always return 0 unless you have for some reason positioned your body element. if you are wanting the position of the screen from the top of the body you want to use scrollTop()

Comment: not quite `$('body').offset().top` return `0` if you have your css like this `* { margin:0; padding:0 }`, then `$('body').height()` return `0` if nothing on the page, and `$('body').scrollTop()` return always `0`

Comment: that may be true , but i think thats the point. trying to work out where the page will jump to not the positioning of the body. $("body").offset(); will never give you the scroll position